# "pip install gym" leads to "'module' object is not callable" error

Tags: python, anaconda, typeerror

Installing an environment from Git leads to an error. I clone and access the environment perfectly fine, but installing "gym" leads to an "object not callable error".

Here's my code (pretty simple): 
`pip install gym`

And here's the error in full: `File "/Users/name/opt/anaconda3/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

I have already tried exporting the python path, but that did not work.

Comment: Problem solved. ```easy_install pip``` did the trick.

Comment: Worked like a charm